# Symfony2 / Doctrine multiple joins returns error

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm

I'm building a system with messages that can be assigned to (one or more) users.

**Table: Messages**

- id
- text

**Table: Assignments**

- id
- remark
- status

**Table: Assignment_User**

- id
- assignment_id
- user_id

**Table: Users**

- id
- name

Now I want to retrieve all assigned messages for a specific user

```
    $qb->select('DISTINCT m')
    ->from('MessageBundle:Assignment', 'a')
    ->join('MessageBundle:Message', 'm')
    ->join('MessageBundle:AssignmentUser', 'au')
    ->where('a.message = m')
    ->andWhere('au.assignment = a')
    ->andWhere('a.status = (:assigned)')
    ->setParameter('assigned', 'assigned')
    ->orderBy("mr.createdAt", "desc");
```

As soon as I add that second JOIN it throws an error...
Error: Expected Literal, got 'JOIN'

What would be the correct way to get all assigned messages for user X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine should already understand how your tables relate through your entity mappings (if not, you might need to set those up first). Rather than trying to join a whole table and then specifying what the table is joined on (SQL-style), just join, for example, `au.assignment` *as* `a`.

At that point, you can also specify any additional conditions on your join, such as you'd want on `a.status`.

You might prefer to reorder the joins below depending on what associations you have set up in which directions (I don't know whether your `Message` has an `assignments` property, for example).

```
$qb->select('DISTINCT m')
->from('MessageBundle:AssignmentUser', 'au')
->innerJoin('au.assignment', 'a', 'WITH', 'a.status = (:assigned)')
->innerJoin('au.user', 'u')
->innerJoin('a.message', 'm')
->where('u.id = (:user_id)')
->setParameter('assigned', 'assigned')
->setParameter('user_id', $yourSpecificUserId)
->orderBy("m.createdAt", "desc");
```