# How can I join multiple tables in symfony2?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am working on a project. I am using symfony2 with XAMPP with PHP version of 5.5.19. I have three tables that have relationship ..

Here are the tables :

```
table_name : transaction_tbl 
- transaction_id
-filename
-filepath
-sender
-doctype_id

table_name : doctype_tbl
-doctype_id
- doctype
-name
-description

table_name : transaction_details

- details_id
-ref_numbers
-amount
-transaction_id
```

what I want to do is to join the three tables so I can get the doctype with its details. Meaning need to join also the transaction and the transaction details. I don't know how to do it. Can somebody help ?

**UPDATE**

I forgot to say that I am using doctrine query builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$qb->select('DISTINCT m')
->from('MessageBundle:AssignmentUser', 'au')
->innerJoin('au.assignment', 'a', 'WITH', 'a.status = (:assigned)')
->innerJoin('au.user', 'u')
->innerJoin('a.message', 'm')
->where('u.id = (:user_id)')
->setParameter('assigned', 'assigned')
->setParameter('user_id', $yourSpecificUserId)
->orderBy("m.createdAt", "desc");
```

See [Symfony2 / Doctrine multiple joins returns error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989473/symfony2-doctrine-multiple-joins-returns-error) for details.

Comment: why does it give method for object does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is probably to use Doctrine ORM, define your entities and their relations with annotations, and use Doctrine QueryBuilder to interact with your data.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html.

Comment: I am using doctrine query builder.. Can you give me example on how should I do it? I am new to this one. :)

Comment: Ok that was an important piece of information missing :-) 
See @kailash-sharma answer for an example.