# Symfony Join Multiple tables

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

iam trying to join multiple tables in my bundle using DQL and

Error:

```
 [Syntax Error] line 0, col 610: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'CarparkFueltext'
```

Entity:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9fc7bfe89bb54427f89c

Code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/63680019a3f260733dca

I have also tried with createQueryBuilder() method

Code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/92012697fc99fcf02da5

ERROR:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 423: Error: Expected Literal, got 'JOIN'
```

However if i remove either of the join statements

```
JOIN MyBundle:SpareParts\CarparkAgestext CarparkAgestext
```

OR

```
JOIN MyBundle:SpareParts\CarFueltext CarFueltext
```

I am getting the data.

The error seems to be that I cannt join multiple tables and i need to join atleast 5 tables to it. Any Idea how can i acheive it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I join multiple tables in symfony2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31199659/how-can-i-join-multiple-tables-in-symfony2)

Comment: I tried adding other tables its still the same error

Comment: can you give the code of your entities (in order to see the mapping), then it will be easy to answer your question

Comment: I uploaded the code... the entities are unidirectional ManyToOne Relationship

Answer (score 2):

Join syntax is [here](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L967).

General example:

```
    ...
    ->select(['e1'])
    ->from('AcmeDemoBundle:Entity1', 'e1')
    ->innerJoin('AcmeDemoBundle:Entity2', 'e2', 'WITH', 'e2.e1 = e1')
    ->innerJoin('AcmeDemoBundle:Entity3', 'e3', 'WITH', 'e3.e2 = e2')
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join multiple tables, but you need to use the right [association](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) of `MyBundle:SpareParts\Carparktype`.

You should use a query like the following one:

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select($fields)
        ->from('MyBundle:SpareParts\Carparktype Carparktype')
        ->innerJoin('Carparktype.agesText CarparkAgestext')
        ->where('Carparktype.makename =:makename')
        ->andWhere('CarparkAgestext.id =:agesid')
        ->setParameter('makename',$makename)
        ->setParameter('agesid',$param)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

As you see you will build a JOIN statement starting from a single property of `SpareParts\Carparktype`, which will be mapped as an *association* (a foreign key) for `SpareParts\CarparkAgestext`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're trying to JOIN two tables with no relationship defined. If that's the case you can JOIN them using WITH

```
FROM FooBundle:Entity1 e1 JOIN FooBundle:Entity2 e2 WITH e2.e1_id = e1.id
```

Comment: No the two tables have relationship if not how could i get the data with only ONE Join statement..?


I dont get data only if I have morethan ONE Join statements

Comment: In Doctrine, like MySQL, you can JOIN tables, no matter if they have a relationship or not, using the syntax I provided in my post.

Comment: Okay I got it... I am now able to see the data.. I wonder why it didnt work with CreateQueryBuilder and createQuery methods

Comment: It seems like the relationship is some how broken... Idk where

Comment: I think you should define them in a more standard way. "id" for primary keys, "name_of_entity_id" for foreign keys. you don't need @ORM\JoinColumns({}) with only one JoinColumn inside, so you can remove it. Keep it simple and it'll be less error-prone.